# Set look-at camera attribute on javascript created a-box

Tags: aframe

I'm creating several a-frame (version 0.60) objects in javascript dynamically, I manage to set all sorts of attributes successfully.
When it comes to a look-at attribute to set to the camera, it is ignored.
This is the markup I use:

```
    <a-camera id="camera" camera look-controls>
       <a-cursor id="cursor" color="#FF0000"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
```

And the js code:

```
    var aboxEl = document.createElement('a-box');
    aboxEl.setAttribute('look-at', 'camera');
```

Thank you for any hint

Answer (score 0):

thank to Andrew who told me to add the look-at component source.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/aframe-look-at-component/master/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
```

the funny thing is that you don't have to add the look-at source when doing markup